# Matomo vuejs sometimes return undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, matomo

I have this code :

```
Vue.use(VueMatomo, {
    host: 'myhost.com',
    siteId: 2,
    trackerFileName: 'piwik',
    router,
    enableLinkTracking: true,
    requireConsent: false,
    trackInitialView: true,
    disableCookies: false,
    requireCookieConsent: false,
    enableHeartBeatTimer: false,
    heartBeatTimerInterval: 15,
    debug: false,
    userId: undefined,
    cookieDomain: undefined,
    domains: undefined,
    preInitActions: [],
});
```

In package.json I have : `"vue-matomo": "^4.0.0"`.

What I try to do is after login, to set the user id, I do like this : `this.$matomo.setUserId(100)`. The problem is that I have undefined the I do `console.log(this.$matomo)`. There is a way to solve this issue ? Thx in advance

Comment: use require("vue-matomo") before Vue.use

Comment: @NegiRox the same issue

Comment: i'd recommend to ask in the Vuejs repository issue tracker? They might be able to help better